# Java implementation of Binary Tree of Linked Lists

Tags: java, linked-list, binary-tree, nodes

I'm creating a program which stores the jobs done for a client inside a `LinkedList` and the `LinkedList` represents a client. How can I achieve that my `LinkedList`s are added to a binary tree as the nodes so I can easily search for clients and then look at their jobs?

So far I have coded a linkedList and the job class, but I haven't made the binary tree yet

Comment: Do you have any code that you've already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before all you should consider using classes. This will make your code more manageable and readable. For starters let me suggest:

```
class Client extends LinkedList<Job> {...}
```

You can change this later on as it fits your needs.

Now simple use a TreeMap to store them:

```
TreeMap<String,Client> clients = new TreeMap<>();
```

Comment: Does this mean that i just extend the node in the binary tree into a linkedList?

Comment: You need a way to identify/lookup the client. I assumed this is done by name. So what you get with my snippets is a binary tree which stores Strings (the clients' names) as key and the Client object itself as value for this key.